# Can't get jQuery AJAX to work on the unload tried EVERY post and still nothing

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, asynchronous

this is the code that isnt working

```
        $( window ).bind("beforeunload",function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                async: false,
                url: "dir",
                data: {REMID: "<?LOGPOSTID?>"}
            }).done(function(msg){alert(msg)});
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                async: false,
                url: "dir",
                data: {REMID: "<?LOGPOSTID?>"}
            });
        });
```

the "done" function on the end of the first ajax doesnt show up and im not sure where its going wrong

Answer (score 3):

Any AJAX request bound to the `beforeunload` event isn't guaranteed to be made before the page is unloaded. Once the page has started to unload, the AJAX will be cancelled.

If the same code works in say a `click` event handler but not here, this is probably the reason why.